# Lua booleans don't have expected behavior in redis

Tags: string, lua, redis, match, string-matching

I have a script

```
local fields = redis.call('hkeys', 'a:hash:full:of:stuff');
local retval = {};
for i, field in pairs(fields) do
    if((string.match(tostring(field),'ev')) ~= nil) then
        retval[i] = {field, (string.match(tostring(field),'ev') ~= nil) }
    end
end
return retval
```

this script returns an empty list

when I change the `if` statement to look like

```
if((string.match(tostring(field),'.')) ~= nil) then
    ...
```

I get a long list that includes the following

```
...
...
60) 1) "applet:1:metric:viewelement:20130607"
    2) (nil)
61) 1) "applet:1:total_events:20130529"
    2) (integer) 1
...
...
```

if I replace the if statement with

```
if(1)
```

I get the same long list of keys

I've also tried using `string.find`, and it has similar behavior.

The only thing that *seems* to be a pattern is that the `if` statement will pass if the matched string appears more than once in the string, or if it appears at the beginning.  I can't be very sure on that, but it might help.

I am running this script using the following command

```
$ redis-cli eval "$(cat get_keys.lua)" 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't need to do `if((string.match(tostring(field),'ev')) ~= nil)`. You can just do `if(string.match(tostring(field),'ev'))`.
2. The reason your script fails is that lua does not support nil keys in a table. If you set `some_table[1]`, `some_table[2]`, and `some_table[5]` and then return the array, it'll look like it ends at `some_table[2]`. Since you only set the array when your if statement passes, if it fails on `retval[1]`, none of the rest of the array will ever be returned.

The simple fix is:

```
local fields = redis.call('hkeys', 'a:hash:full:of:stuff');
local retval = {};
for i, field in pairs(fields) do
    if(string.match(tostring(field),'ev')) then
        retval[i] = {field, (string.match(tostring(field),'ev') ~= nil) }
    else retval[i] = 'some_nil_value'
    end
end
return retval
```

I think you can also use [table default values](http://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.3.html), but I haven't played with those yet, so can't give too much info here.

**[EDIT]** The OP stated he doesn't want nil placeholders. In that case, the following can be used:

```
local fields = redis.call('hkeys', 'a:hash:full:of:stuff');
local retval = {};
for i, field in pairs(fields) do
    if(string.match(tostring(field),'ev')) then
        retval[#retval+1] = {field, (string.match(tostring(field),'ev') ~= nil) }
    end
end
return retval
```

Comment: Yes.  There was a bit of extra stuff in the script from debugging.  This works, but isn't optimal

Comment: @PeterKlipfel in what way is it not optimal? You might be able to squeeze a tiny bit more performance out of using default tables, but I doubt it'll make any difference in benchmarks.

Comment: What I meant by that is what I put in my answer.  I should have specified that it isn't optimal for my use case, which would include parsing out the nil values that were put in the array.  I'm sure my solution could be prettied up, but it uses less memory

Comment: Your original solution had an array of the exact size of your `hkeys` call being returned with nil placeholders. If you wanted to avoid the nil placeholders, why did you ask the question in the first place? Anyway, I'll modify my answer with a cleaner way to avoid placeholders, if that's what you want.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't mean to sound like a punk.  I put up my answer because in the case that anyone comes across this answer, the gotcha might help debug.  It has the benefit of returning a smaller list.  I wasn't sure why I wasn't getting my list back

Answer (score 0):

Eli's answer works, but I think the reason for this is a subtle gotcha in the way that lists are handled in Lua.  I wanted to explain what I think is going on.

So, as a test, I inserted an extra field in `retval`, and occasionally it was nil.  I noticed that on those calls, the rest of the list was not returned.

What I think is happening under the hood is that redis is working through the whole list, but then when it gets returned, it is truncated at the first `nil`.  So sometimes there's a list, and sometimes there isn't.  As a hack, I rewrote the script as

```
local fields = redis.call('hkeys', 'a:hash:full:of:stuff');
local retval = {};
local i = 0
for j, field in pairs(fields) do
    if string.find(field,"ev") then
        retval[i] = {field, string.match(field,'ev') }
        i = i+1;
    end
end
return retval
```

and it worked!

So Eli's answer works because `retval` isn't being truncated.  However, it uses up more bandwidth and cpu time when you need to parse through the returned list